# Getting length of an object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var l={"a":1,"b":2,"c":5};
```

I want to get the length of this

```
alert(l.length);
```

but that returns `undefined`. Obviously I'm looking to get `3` as the answer.

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: I assume this is demonstration code, but can I just say that using a lowercase L as a name is an easy way to confuse your variable with the number one?

Comment: @Blazemonger: If you're concerned about muddling symbols, you need a better font / syntax highlighter. Don't change your code just because you have poor tools.

Comment: @Eric Besides the fact that it's OFTEN easy to confuse l and 1, regardless of font, it's worth pointing out that using single-character names for variables is almost always a bad idea. There's no good reason not to spell out what the variable IS in order to make your code self-commenting. You likewise shouldn't use, for example, `myobject` and `myObject` as two distinct variables just because JavaScript is case-sensitive -- it easily leads to confusion and it's never necessary.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I'm not saying that `l` is a good variable name. You're right, it's not. However, I couldn't justify changing to `m` or `L` just because it might be confused.

Comment: @Eric Then get a better keyboard. It's always incumbent on the speaker (or programmer) to ensure his ideas (or variables) are clear and unmistakable. Blaming the listener (or next programmer) for failing to see through one's own lack of clarity is unprofessional and lazy.

Comment: x1a4, I see James McLaughlin fixed that (Thanks James). You're right, it's an object. It is how json_encode outputs an array though. So it would be useful to have a browser independent way of checking the length of an object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can count the number of entries in an object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which returns an array of the keys in the object:

```
var l = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
Object.keys(l).length;
```

However, it might be more efficient (and cross browser) to implement your own property:

```
Object.length = function(obj) {
    var i = 0;
    for(var key in obj) i++;
    return i;
}

Object.length(l);
```

Note that although I could have defined the function as `Object.prototype.length`, allowing you to write `l.length()`, I didn't, because that would fail if your object container the key `length`.

Comment: Just a heads up that `Object.keys()` is ES5, so browser support will be dodgy.

Comment: @jmar777 [So polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatiblity).

Answer (score 1):

```
var l={"a":1,"b":2,"c":5};
Object.keys(l).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function count(O){
    for(var p in O){
        if(O.hasOwnProperty(p))++cnt;
    }
    return cnt;
}
count(l);
```